# Is the installation order for Dell blades firmware updates important?

Tags: dell, blade-server

This weekend, we're going to be upgrading the firmware on our Dell Blades. We've complied a list of components and relative importance (i.e. Urgent, Recommended, Optional).

My question is: does the order that we upgrade the firmware matter?

Comment: `1.` Why would you post a link to your Service Tag in this question? That doesn't strike me as particularly prudent. `2.` You have an active support contract on that piece of equipment so why wouldn't you just call Dell and ask them? My first call would be to the vendor, not some random question and answer site you found on the internet.

Comment: Well, start with the manuals for the equipment, and then the release notes for the firmware updates in question. Only then would I call the vendor if I was still unsure or confused. But yeah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing - firmware is firmware (hardware) and drives are software components in the running OS. Please use the correct terms.

Yup, read the release notes for each component and find out if it depends on a specific firmware version of another component. Make sure that the CMC (Chassis Management Controller) in the chassis itself is also considered when doing this!

If it doesn't, I will typically do DRAC, BIOS, RAID, and then other components like NIC, HBA, etc.

After you upgrade the firmware(s), find out if you also need driver updates in your OS, as applicable.